# how to add quotes to all elements in the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

my ruby code in rails:

```
 WebFontConfig = {
          google: { families: [<%= @text %>] }
        }
```

gives me the outcome like this:

```
 WebFontConfig = {
          google: { families: [Aclonica,Aclonica,Acme,Acme,Aclonica] }
        }
```

But I need outcome like this:

```
  WebFontConfig = {
              google: { families: ['Aclonica','Acme'] }
            }
```

So I need ad ' around words and take only unique recored. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this sample is erb template.

And @text has defined in controller like as `@text = 'Aclonica,Aclonica,Acme,Acme,Aclonica'`

In this case, you can use next simple regexp:

```
WebFontConfig = {
  google: { families: [<%= @text.split(',').uniq.join(',').gsub(/[^,]+/, "'\\0'").html_safe %>] }
}
```

Comment: I go this: [&#x27;Alegreya&#x27;,&#x27;Acme&#x27;]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method you could use to do that.

```
input = "Aclonica,Aclonica,Acme,Acme,Aclonica"

def format(text_string = "")
  text_string
    .split(",")
    .uniq
    .map { |string| "'" + string + "'" }
    .join(", ")
end

format(input) #=> "'Aclonica', 'Acme'"
```